# find limit using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

I know that when we are approaching the origin, we can always take the limit as r approaches 0. But what if we are not approaching zero? For example
$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (4,3)}\frac{x ^2-1}{3x+y}=1$ by direct ssubstitution.

If I were to use polar coordinates instead, $x=r\cos \theta$, $y=r\sin \theta$, $r=x^2+y^2$.

leads me to $\frac{r^2\cos^2 \theta-1}{3r\cos \theta +r\sin \theta}=\frac{25\cos^2\theta -1}{15\cos \theta +5\sin \theta}$. This and 1?, how can this possible be 1?

Comment: In neighbourhood of $(4,3)$ you have fraction of continuous functions with denominator $\neq 0$. So you can directly obtain answer $\frac{15}{15}=1$. Is it necessary to use polar coordinates?

Comment: @zkutch, I don' t really have to use polar. I just never came across any example where we are not approaching the origin and polar coordinates are used to find the limit. I know that changing coordinates may simplify or complicate the problem, I just want to know if we can only use polar coordinates when we are approaching the origin? Is this right, if not, an appropriate example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on polar coordinates, then $(4,3)$ in polar coordinates gives $r=5$, $\sin \theta =\frac{3}{5}$ and $\cos \theta =\frac{4}{5}$. As denominator is not zero, then you can directly insert values and obtain
$$\frac{5^2 \frac{4^2}{5^2}-1}{3\cdot 5 \cdot \frac{4}{5} +5 \frac{3}{5} }=1$$
As I wrote in comment same can be obtained directly in $x,y$ coordinates.